# HTTP Post - XML URL Encoding

Tags: xml, http-post, filemaker

I am trying to post some xml to a website api called vid.ly, a video hosting site. My lack of knowledge of HTTP Post and XML means I don't really know how to encode the XML for posting. The instructions are as follows

> Vidly accepts XML requests sent on http://m.vid.ly/api/ URL via simple HTTP POST (please note, you should keep trailing slash in URL).
>
> XML should be placed in xml POST parameter.
>   In response Vidly sends XML as well.
>   You can try it right away on the API test page: http://m.vid.ly/test/test_api.php.

The XML string I am trying to send, and I know works (although if you try it, the UserID has been changed for security) as I have tested it in their test box is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Query>
<Action>GetMediaList</Action>
<UserID>694</UserID>
<UserKey>434dd012aaa9ccbf48fa681b792bfagd</UserKey>
<Count>10</Count> <!-- optional -->
</Query>
```

I am trying to incorporate it into a program called filemaker but right now I would really love someone to show me how to get a response from any HTTP Post environment. If someone could show me how to get a response in 'www.Hurl.it' that would be incredibly helpful. All I ever get as a response is 'No XML present'.

Thanks

James

Comment: FileMaker supports HTTP-POST in recent versions (at least 13 and 14). 
Limitation is content-type only application/x-www-form-urlencoded, you need application/xml. So this will be only possible with plugin or calling an external app.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the (free) BaseElements plugin.

Answer (score 0):

FileMaker supports HTTP Post in recent versions, at least 13 and 14. Limitation is only content-type x-www-formencoded.  I'm not sure wether this is enough for this problem.

[Additional info:]

I tried it and it works with FileMaker.  A script is required with this step:

```
Insert from URL [ Select ; <your-result-field> ; "httppost://manage.encoding.com" & "?xml=" & GetAsURLEncoded ( <your-xml> )]
```

[Not required because it is possible in FileMaker directly:]

In every case it is possible to do this with drakma, see http://weitz.de/drakma, Common Lisp library.

Toolset http://weitz.de/fm-plugin-tools/ allows to build filemaker plugins.  It requires a licence of http://lispworks.com professional.  This is possibly a bit much for this simple problem.

If you can solve this in PHP of Java, there are also plugins for FileMaker which support these languages.

~jens

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I didn't realise that the vidly server was unable to read url-encoded xml and  that filemaker can't read application xml. Is there a way to do this in excel or google sheets, I need something relatively straightforward that my little brain can handle :)

Comment: An easy way would be CURL (http://curl.haxx.se/).  How to handle this depends on your OS, are you on Windows?

Comment: I am using a windows machine though ideally I would create something that works with mac's too. Do you mean to say you actually got the request to work within Filemaker? As that would be great! If not, I have discovered that I am able to get a server response using a very simple http script. Could this be automated somehow outside of filemaker to generate an xml? Thanks for your help

Comment: <form action="http://m.vid.ly/api/" method="POST">
 <div><input type="submit"></div>
 <div><textarea name="xml_text" style="width: 800px; height: 450px; margin-top: 10px;">
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<Query>

<Action>GetMediaList</Action>
<UserID>694</UserID>
<UserKey>434dd012aaa9dcbf48fa681b792bfacd</UserKey>
<Count>1000</Count> <!-- optional -->
</Query>

Comment: Yes it works within FileMaker, I can send my demo database if you tell me your email.  Mine is info-at-jensteich-dot-de.

Comment: wow, that would be absolutely amazing, my email is jamesmgharding@gmail.com Thank you!!